# Multiple update api hits returning inconsistent result in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose I have created an update API, but it always returns inconsistence result.
My Schema for it is :-

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    BookID: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, required:true },
    BookAuthor: { type: String, index:{unique:true} },
    BookVersion: { type:String},
    IsbnNo: { type:Number }
});
```

My Query is:-

```
api.route('/UpdateBookbyBookId/:BookServerID')
    .put(function(req,res){
        Book.update({BookServerID : req.body.BookServerID},{$set: { "BookAuthor": req.body.BookAuthor} },function(err,vctestData){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                res.json({success:false, message: 'Update failed!'+err, errorCode:err.code });return
            }
            if(vctestData.nModified==0){
                res.json({success:false,message: 'Unable to modify!', errorCode:null });
            }else{
                res.json({success:true,message: 'Details Updated!', errorCode:null });
            }                
        })
})
```

But it returns inconsistence result:-

Log 1

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
```

Log 2

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }
```

My FrontEnd team is hitting this API twice sometimes thrice when they are manipulating update book API on UI, which returns when unable to "nModified: 0" or sometimes when data is modified "nModified: 1", can someone explain to me why this is happening.

Comment: I'm kind of predisposed to think you really mean `{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }`, because that's by design when the update statement **"would not change the data from what it already is"** as it essentially means that `n` documents where "matched" by `0` documents were "modified", purely because there was no change to be applied. If you see `n: 0` then that just means *"nothing matched **at all**"*, which is really an artifact of the query condition not matching any documents.

Comment: Also this is **NOT** a "multi" update. To do that, you **must** include the `{ multi: true }` option. Or more preferably, use the `updateMany()` method from the API, which applies that option automatically. Usage of the underlying plain `.update()` directly is essentially considered deprecated, and you should be using `updateOne()` or `updateMany()` as is appropriate to what you really mean.

Comment: earlier I was using, findOneAndUpdate, but it was not updating properly hence changed it to update for a proper response, please check my schema and let me know if my query is correct or not.